# AngularJS getting in trouble with my JSON

Tags: json, angularjs

I have got a JSON object from my website:

```
{ "ID":"102”,
 "role":{“subscriber”:true},
 "first_name”:”Test 3”,
 "last_name”:”Test 4”,
 "custom_fields":{ “job_title”:”testing”},
}
```

and AngularJS to manage the dynamic content but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

 function PeopleCtrl($scope, $http) {

$scope.people = [];

$scope.loadPeople = function () {
    var httpRequest = $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/echo/json/',
        data: mockDataForThisTest

    }).success(function (data, status) {
        $scope.people = data;
    });

};
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qag0jwkg/).

Can anybody help me with displaying data?

Comment: you have errors in console

Comment: What version of Angular?

Comment: The console errors show the issue isn't Angular managing the content, it's with Angular initializing. I don't know enough about JSfiddle to help beyond that

Comment: check my comment to my answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@qqruza to get the callback working properly in your [jsfiddle.net/1zuteco7](http://jsfiddle.net/1zuteco7), change the url to this:

```
http://test.eventident.com/api/last_posts/siteid=&callpage=1&perpage=10&callback=JSON_CALLBACK
```

Notice the `JSON_CALLBACK` in the end. The rest of your app will still not work though cause you are not picking the right bindings from the returned data in your repeat directive. Try `console.log(data)` in the success function to click through the returned object and get to the right paths.

Comment: I really appreciate your help @chris

Comment: I have updated your jsfiddle to one that works: [http://jsfiddle.net/bnxy20h8/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/bnxy20h8/1/). This one retrieves the authors from the result array and pushes each author into `$scope.people`. Then whatever's defined in the author fields will show up in your view. I have also added a function that checks for duplicates (using author ID) before pushing a new author in the array.

Answer (score 1):

There were a number of issues with your JSON, I have resolved them.

It had different types of quotes in there. I have replaced them with `"`.

It now looks like this:

```
[{         
  "ID": "100",
  "role": {            
    "subscriber": true         
  },
  "first_name": "Test",
  "last_name": "Test2",
  "custom_fields": {            
    "job_title": "subscriber"         
  },
}, {   
  "ID": "102",
  "role": {            
    "subscriber": true         
  },
  "first_name": "Test 3",
  "last_name": "Test 4",
  "custom_fields": {            
    "job_title": "testing"         
  },        
}]
```

Also, you were not referencing the model fields correctly in your view.

Here is the updated working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kmmmv83y/1/

Answer (score 0):

You had a comma at the end of the last property, that will typically error everything out, the below JSON should work:

```
{ "ID":"102”,
 "role":{“subscriber”:true},
 "first_name”:”Test 3”,
 "last_name”:”Test 4”,
 "custom_fields":{ “job_title”:”testing”}
}
```